# "Time Capsules" in the architectural plans of Catholic Churches and Cathedrals?

Tags: catholicism, church-local, architecture

I found this article about a [time capsule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_capsule) found in a Catholic Church in Singapore quite interesting: [173-year-old time capsule unearthed at Singapore's oldest Catholic church](https://www.straitstimes.com/singapore/rare-finds-at-spores-oldest-catholic-church)

> A 173-year-old time capsule and granite foundation stone of the country's oldest Catholic church have been unearthed, in what experts describe as a "rare discovery".
>
> Contractors found the hitherto missing capsule and foundation stone earlier this year while restoring the Cathedral of the Good Shepherd along Queen Street.
>
> The time capsule - possibly the oldest one found here - comprises publications such as a prayer booklet and newspapers from 1843, as well as 24 international 18th- and 19th-century coins and tokens. A foundation stone, or cornerstone, is the first stone set in the construction of a masonry foundation.

Does the Catholic Church have any regulations (rules, laws or norms) on placing a time capsule in the foundation of a church or cathedral? What may placed in such a time capsule?

As a bonus question: What is the oldest known recorded evidence of a time capsule ever been employed in the Catholic architecture of a church or cathedral?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the concept of a time capsule is fairly recent (since the late 1700s) whereas a lot of Catholic churches are older than that.  In fact, the natural tendency of Catholicism to keep records and create art makes their churchs de facto time capsules of enormous historical worth.